# Shopify / Liquid - using case / when loop, whilst updating cart item quantity

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, liquid

I am using the following liquid loop:

```
{%- for option in variant_options -%}
  <li class="product-details__item product-details__item--variant-option" data-cart-item-option>
    {% case option.value %}
      {% when 'S' %}
      Small
      {% when 'M' %}
      Medium
      {% when 'L' %}
      Large
    {% endcase %}
  </li>
{%- endfor -%}
```

This fine works on initial page load, but when you change the quantity of any of the products in the cart, it makes every cart item's option.value return to the original option.value - ie it refreshes them and makes it look as if the case / when loop doesn't exist.

I suspect its javascript driven, but any ideas/solutions welcome.

I am using standard shopify debut theme.

Comment: Can you provide more details like where you are using the code, what is the expected outcome etc.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Liquid is being used for templating on the initial page load, so the values do not then keep track of changes made by the user.

Shopify has an [AJAX API](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/ajax-api/reference/cart#get-cart-js) where you can get the contents of the shopping cart, so you could use JavaScript to do this.

```js
let updateList = () => {
   fetch('/cart.js')
   .then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json
   .then(function(data) {
      let i = 0;
      let j = 0;
      let lis = '';
      let optName = '';

      for (i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
         for (j = 0; j < data.items[i]['variant_options'].length; i++) {
            switch(data.items[i]['variant_options'][j]) {
            case 'S':
               optName = 'Small';
               break;
            case 'M':
               optName = 'Medium';
               break;
            case 'L':
               optName = 'Large';
               break;
            default:
               continue;
            };

            lis += '<li class="product-details__item product-details__item--variant-option" data-cart-item-option>' + optName + '</li>';
         };
      };

      //Write lis to page where appropriate
      document.getElementById('element').innerHTML = lis;
      
   })
   .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
   });
};

//Add event handlers to call this function, e.g.:
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.action_button.add_to_cart, .product-plus.js-change-quantity, .product-minus.js-change-quantity');
let i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
   btns[i].addEventListener('click', updateList);
};
```

In the above code, a function is created which retrieves the cart contents, goes through it and writes your list of variants to the page.

It then sets event handlers to call this function when relevant buttons on the page are clicked (Add to Cart, Increase Quantity, Decrease Quantity).